# printing all directories and subdirectories function

Tags: bash, directory

I'm trying to print all subdirectories, using the function below but for some reason when the file name include spaces (" "), the `echo` splits the name into two parts. Here is an example:

My directory includes a file called `r1    August.request`.

The output is:

```
r1

August.request
```

and I'm looking for

```
r1     August.request
```

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function ScanFile {
    for file in `ls` ; do  
    if [[ -d "$file" ]] ; then
            cd "$file"
            ScanFile
            cd ..
            else
            echo "$file"
    fi
    done
} 
ScanFile
```

Comment: Can you not just use the find command?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is so called IFS variable in SH compliant shells. IFS stands for **Internal Field Separator**. This variable controls how the shell detects parameter boundaries like in positional arguments.

By default it is:

```
set IFS=$' \t\n'
```

Which translates to: split the input into tokens separated by space, tab and new line.

Your files consists of white spaces. Try doing it this way:

```
OLD_IF="$IFS"
IFS=$'\t\n'
for file in `ls -1` ; do
     # Content of your loop
done
IFS="$OLD_IFS"
```

Here the catch is to store previous IFS value and restore it.

Edit: added `ls -1` as this lists one file per line hence does the stuff you've mentioned.

Comment: ...until you have filenames with tabs or newlines in them...

Comment: ... and then you modify IFS accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

In bash:

```
shopt -s globstar
ls -1d **/
```

Comment: thanks for replaying but indeed that didn't help :(

Comment: It lists all the directories and subdirectories from your current location, doesn't it?

Comment: yup it is! how can i presint them at the same line at a template of <directory><subdirectory> 
(newline )<directory><subdirectory>
and dont let him spit the spaces to two lines

Comment: It prints them one per line, just like your script seems to be trying to do...?

Comment: as an example I have directory include file with name
 "r1 August.request" I'm looking for output like "r1 August.request" but I'm getting :

"r1

August.request"

Comment: Perhaps the `-l` flag to ls is what's wrong? Try with the number `1`: `ls -1d **/`

Comment: I appreciate ur effort but not working i guess the mistake at echo it split the space to the new line... or can u upload the code ur talking about my i missed something thanks again <3

Comment: I've edited the answer to use a one instead of an "ell"

Answer (score 0):

Your function parses the unquoted output of `ls`.  This means that the shell will perform word splitting (by default on any whitespace) and filename generation (globbing) on the output of `ls`.

Instead:

```
dirwalk () {
    indent=${1:-0}

    for name in *; do
        [ ! -e "$name" ] && continue
        if [ -d "$name" ]; then
            printf '%*sDir: "%s"\n' "$indent" "" "$name"
            ( cd "$name" && dirwalk "$(( indent + 4 ))" )
        else
            printf '%*sFile: "%s"\n' "$indent" "" "$name"
        fi
    done
}
```

or, without the fancy indentation,

```
dirwalk () {
    for name in *; do
        [ ! -e "$name" ] && continue
        if [ -d "$name" ]; then
            printf 'Dir: "%s"\n' "$name"
            ( cd "$name" && dirwalk )
        else
            printf 'File: "%s"\n' "$name"
        fi
    done
}
```

By using `*` instead of the output of `ls`, we generate a properly delimited list of filenames to iterate over in the current directory, even if these contain spaces.

The `-e` test is to make sure that the thing that we iterate over actually exists.  If we enter an empty directory, the `*` would not expand and would remain as `*`.  In `bash`, you may set the `nullglob` shell option (with `shopt -s nullglob`) to make unmatched patterns expand to nothing instead.

By using `cd` in a subshell (within parentheses), we don't have to remember to `cd ..` to get back to the previous directory. The environment outside of `( ... )` would not be affected by the `cd` inside it.

Using `printf` rather than `echo` we have greater control over the formatting of the output.  Also see "[Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803)".